# Copy the content to another file corrupts the content

Tags: javascript, rendering, gif

If I rename the test.gif file to .txt and copy the content manually to another file and rename it to have extension ".gif" => test1.gif. The gif file "test1.gif" is not rendering.
Also the byte size is increased. Please help in to justify the behavior.

The above experiment I am doing because, I am receiving the gif blob "GIF89a.... " from Rest api but unable to render the gif file.

**The main issue is. Render a gif file whose content "blob" I have received via Rest API**

```
var file = new File([gifRes], "model.gif"); 
console.log('reached');
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file); 
or url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([gifRes]),{type:"image/gif"}); 
var image = new Image(); 
image.src = url document.body.appendChild(image); a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: Okay forget about copying, the main issue is. Render a gif file whose content "blob" I have received via Rest API

Comment: var file = new File([gifRes], "model.gif");

    console.log('reached');

    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

    or 
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([gifRes]),{type:"image/gif"});

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url               document.body.appendChild(image);

    a.click();

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

Comment: What's `gifRes`?

Comment: The content of this file https://github.com/khushbuv/gBowling/blob/master/BowlingGame/model.txt

Comment: Okay, so we're back to copying, I shouldn't have deleted my earlier comment. How is that being transferred? The extension is `.txt`. Does the server send it as text? You can't reliably transfer binary files as text.

Comment: I have changed the extension to see the content inside. Below is the response body.    content-length: 9950587 
 content-type: image/gif 
 date: Tue,07 Nov 2023 22:13:52 GMT 
 etag: 254a8ba2455b0d05bf2677423b98a63c 
 last-modified: Mon,06 Nov 2023 16:52:15 GMT 
 server: uvicorn

Comment: I am just receiving the blob and writing it to a file. But it doesn't render.